# Extracting key-value pairs from OCR text

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, text-mining, data-extraction

Im supposed to use OCR to identify text in legal documents, extract relevant keys and their values (around 40 attributes), and then store them in an excel sheet.

I've already implemented the OCR part, and have my dictionary defined something like this

```
dictionary = {"Lease Term":["<data in years>"], "Rent" : ["<maybe float numbers>"], "Car parking Spaces":["<number of parking spaces>"], Lessor Name:["<String value>"]}
```

My question is once I have the text recognised, and tokenised with nltk, how do I go ahead and actually identify the text needed to be extracted? Sure I can identify the keys in the text, but what's the approach for actually getting the value for the pair?

I read other answers and it seems either regex matching or manually training data with 100 or so sample documents (I have around ~700 of them) is the way to go around doing this, but if I try to explain this conundrum to anyone in my team (who are non-technical finance people), they tend to ignore the jargon, and ask me to implement all of this in a couple of days.

I'm sure both regex and NLP approach will take manual work in the sense I'd have to keep testing on the sample documents that I will get, and that's after implementing them in my code (for which I have to learn those things from scratch).

Please describe an approach which can help solve the issue.

Comment: Did you manage to find a good approach? If yes, please post your solution. :)

Answer (score 2):

AWS Textract will let you detect key-value pairs from a document. It represents extracted form data as key-value pairs. Key-value pairs are returned as Block objects and you can use the 'EntityType' attribute to determine if a block is a KEY or a VALUE. Block object is nothing but a set of linked data items which contains the key-value information

Hope this helps: https://aws.amazon.com/textract/

Comment: how do we implement it without AWS textract ?